# Using PostgreSQL on deployment and MySQL on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel, heroku

In my Laravel 5.3 project, I have used MySQL locally as Database. To deploy the project on Heroku, I had to edit

```
config/database.php
```

to reconfigure my Database so that I can use PostgreSQL on Heroku. In this purpose, I added following codes at the very top of the file according to this tutorial https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-on-heroku-using-a-postgresql-database:

```
$url = parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
$host = $url["host"];
$user = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$database = substr($url["path"], 1);
```

It works absolutely fine on Heroku but when I run my project on localhost it gives following message on top of every page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: host in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\quickExam\config\database.php on line 5
Notice: Undefined index: user in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\quickExam\config\database.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: pass in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\quickExam\config\database.php on line 7
```

My MySQL database on localhost works absolutely fine too!
How can I remove this Notice?

Comment: Do a quick var_dump of $url, to see which elements it consists of. The parse_url function probably differs in output, or required input.

Comment: Looks like you don't have a DATABASE_URL environment variable configured on your localhost.

Comment: Using one DBMS in test and another for deployment is going to cause you pain, though. Time to install PostgreSQL on your computer.